# Adding additional workers to Heroku w/ Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

So my app hit a featured page and now I'm getting tons of hits to my background worker dyno on heroku that I never experienced before... My queue has exploded! Taking 20+ minutes between a job being queued and a job being performed. How can I scale this to make it seconds instead of minutes?

```
/sidekiq.yml
# Configuration file for Sidekiq.
# Options here can still be overridden by cmd line args.
# Place this file at config/sidekiq.yml and Sidekiq will
# pick it up automatically.

# :logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency: 2
:timeout: 8
```

Procfile

```
...
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

Comment: just run more sidekiq dynos. Putting more threads on the same dyno will eventually overload it.

Comment: I increased from 1 to 4 dynos and nothing improved

Comment: Well, try 40 and see. heroku bills by the second, 20 minute experiment will not cost you too much money

Comment: I don't know if redis will even allow that many workers to pull from the queue at once... I will try right now

Comment: very quickly got "ERROR: heartbeat: ERR max number of clients reached". Is that because my Redis only allows 10 connections? I am guessing yes

Comment: Well yeah. Now you have to upgrade redis. You can't run a popular app on free/hobby tiers, you know :)

Comment: Nevermind, it allows 50. Not sure why that isn't enough for 40 workers. I'll try a few less than 40 and see what works.

Comment: Because each worker uses 2 connections? (concurrency=2)

Comment: PG::ConnectionBad now... is that my actual database... I'm a noob at this, I know.

Comment: oh no, each sidekiq worker uses 4 connections, it seems. "A Sidekiq server process requires at least (concurrency + 2) connections." Read more here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis

Comment: Yes, now it's your PG database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165172/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-doughtz).

Answer (score 0):

`concurrency` option in `sidekiq.yml` regulates number of sidekiq workers. You can increase this number, to speed up your performance. There is an issue, however. Sidekiq connects to redis and each worker needs one connection. Your redis provider on heroku usually restricts number of possible connections on free tiers to a rather small number, around 2. So if you have a free redis on heroku, there is a chance, that you can't increase number of workers.

Comment: The free Heroku Redis addon supports 20 connections. The $5 Redistogo plan offers 50.